# Given primary color as cyan, but in api versions below 21 it is coming as black

Tags: android, android-layout

Given `<color name="colorPrimary">#00838F</color>` in colors.xml, but in android api versions below 21 (below lollipop) I'm getting black color whereever I mentioned color as @color/colorPrimary. Tried check colors.xml in values-21, no where I've mentioned black but still not getting the intended primary color.

Comment: Please post colors.xml. Also what theme are you using?

Comment: <color name="colorPrimary">#00838F</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#007378</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#00838F</color>

Comment: In all of my activities I'm using, android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: Please edit your original question. Also what is AppTheme?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the theme that you are using you define primary color attribute:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```